# Used a service to run an alarm in the background but app is getting crashed after every 10 seconds probably

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I have a fragment from where I am calling a service using coroutine and in the service I have set an alarm manager which will invoke broadcastreceiver at the specific time but whenever I run the function it only stays for 10 seconds and get crashed after it

this is my fragment
override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
_binding= FragmentAlarmBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

```
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            callService(System.currentTimeMillis() + (binding.ettime.text.toString().toLong() * 1000))
        }
    }



    return binding.root
}

private suspend fun callService(time: Long) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(requireContext(), AlarmService::class.java)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("TimeSelected", time)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(requireContext(), serviceIntent)
    }
}
```

My service which is called by fragment
class AlarmService: Service() {

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val time = intent?.getLongExtra("TimeSelected", 0) ?: 0

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Log.d("coroutine"," the thread is working in service")
        setAlarm(time)
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

private fun setAlarm(time: Long) {
    val alarmManager: AlarmManager? =
        getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
    Log.d("coroutine"," the setalarm method is working in service")
    val alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    alarmManager?.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time - 3, pendingIntent)
}

override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}
```

and at the end a receiver to call a simple tone

class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {

    try {

        Log.d("coroutine", " the broadcast receiver is called")
        Toast.makeText(context, "it is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {

        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("YourReceiver", "Exception in onReceive: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Comment: post crash/exception/log

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to start a Service because you are not doing any long-running tasks in it.

You can trigger the Alarm in the Activity or Fragment. The AlarmManager with the help of PendingIntent will send the Broadcast.

After that, In the BroadcastReceiver, If you want to perform a long-running task only then start a Service.